# Action in CakePHP makes unexpected redirect

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks

I'm making a site in CakePHP 2.7. I'm have a controller called AdsController.php and created an action called buscar();

In buscar() of AdsController.php:

```
    // método para buscar
    public function buscar(/* $uf = null,
      $city = null,
      $newspaper = null, */
    $year1 = null, $month1 = null, $day1 = null, $year2 = null, $month2 = null, $day2 = null) { // tenho que validar os nulos
        $options = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                "Ad.created >=" => $year1 . '-' . $month1 . '-' . $day1 . ' 00:00:00',
                "Ad.created <=" => $year2 . '-' . $month2 . '-' . $day2 . ' 23:59:59'
            )
        );

        $this->set(
                array(
                    'ad' => $this->Ad->find('first', $options),
                    '_serialize' => array('ad')
                )
        );
    }
```

app/Config/routes.php

```
<?php

Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));

Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));

//Criando RESTful
//Router::mapResources('ads');
// Ativando rotas RESTful
Router::connect('/ads/:year1/:month1/:day1/:year2/:month2/:day2',  array('controller' => 'ads', 'action' => 'buscar'), array(

    'year1' => '[12][0-9]{3}',
    'month1' => '0[1-9]|1[012]',
    'day1' => '0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]',
    'year2' => '[12][0-9]{3}',
    'month2' => '0[1-9]|1[012]',
    'day2' => '0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]',
        )
);


/**
 * Load all plugin routes. See the CakePlugin documentation on
 * how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
 */
CakePlugin::routes();

/**
 * Load the CakePHP default routes. Only remove this if you do not want to use
 * the built-in default routes.
 */
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';


// Ativando extensão .json
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

The index is `http://localhost/classificado`.

When I call the action, for example, `localhost/classificado/ads/buscar/2015/09/01/2015/10/10`, or when I call `localhost/classificado/ads/2015/09/01/2015/10/10`, accordind the routes.php, it go to `localhost/classificado/classificado/ads/add` and throw the error:

> ClassificadoController could not be found.

But I don't redirect to this. Please help me.

Comment: No code in the question is responsible for that redirect

Comment: Can we see your routes? Please, remove the useless code